# how to use apply function/for loop on dataframe column content in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

for context, I'm looking at a dataset of data scientist job titles and job descriptions and I'm trying to identify how much is each degree level is cited in those job description.

I was able to get the code to work on one particular job description, but now I need to do a "for loop" or equivalent to iterate through the 'description column' and count cumulatively the amount of times each level of education was cited.

```
sentence = set(data_scientist_filtered.description.iloc[30].split())
degree_level = {'level_1':{'bachelors','bachelor','ba'},
    'level_2':{'masters','ms','m.s',"master's",'master of science'},
    'level_3':{'phd','p.h.d'}}
results = {}
for key, words in degree_level.items():
    results[key] = len(words.intersection(sentence))
results
```

Sample string would be something like this: 
data_scientist_filtered.description.iloc[30]=

```
 'the team: the data science team is a newly formed applied research team within s&amp;p global ratings that will be responsible for building and executing a bold vision around using machine learning, natural language processing, data science, knowledge engineering, and human computer interfaces for augmenting various business processes.\n\nthe impact: this role will have a significant impact on the success of our data science projects ranging from choosing which projects should be undertaken, to delivering highest quality solution, ultimately enabling our business processes and products with ai and data science solutions.\n\nwhat’s in it for you: this is a high visibility team with an opportunity to make a very meaningful impact on the future direction of the company. you will work with senior leaders in the organization to help define, build, and transform our business. you will work closely with other senior scientists to create state of the art augmented intelligence, data science and machine learning solutions.\n\nresponsibilities: as a data scientist you will be responsible for building ai and data science models. you will need to rapidly prototype various algorithmic implementations and test their efficacy using appropriate experimental design and hypothesis validation.\n\nbasic qualifications: bs in computer science, computational linguistics, artificial intelligence, statistics, or related field with 5+ years of relevant industry experience.\n\npreferred qualifications:\nms in computer science, statistics, computational linguistics, artificial intelligence or related field with 3+ years of relevant industry experience.\nexperience with financial data sets, or s&amp;p’s credit ratings process is highly preferred.
```

Sample dataframe:

```
 position       company       description             location
data scientist  Xpert Staffing  this job is for..      Atlanta, GA
data scientist  Cotiviti     great opportunity of..   Atlanta, GA
```

Comment: your code does not have the correct indentaion

Comment: copy error, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the [isin()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) method here, then getting the sum.

```
data = [['John',"ba"],['Harry',"ms"],['Bill',"phd"],['Mary', 'bachelors']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['name','description'])

degree_level = {
    'level_1':{'bachelors','bachelor','ba'},
    'level_2':{'masters','ms','m.s',"master's",'master of science'},
    'level_3':{'phd','p.h.d'}
}

results = {}
for level, values in degree_level:
    results[level] = data_scientist_filtered['description'].isin(values).sum()

print(results)
#{"level_1": 2, "level_2": 1, "level_3": 1}
```

**Edit**
The for loop can be replaced by a comprehension, just FYI.

```
def num_of_degrees(degrees):
    return data_scientist_filtered['description'].isin(values).sum()

results = {level: num_of_degrees(values) for level, values in degree_level}
```

**Edit 2**

With you showing what the df looks like, now I see what the issue is.
You need to [filter()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) the `df` then get the `count()`.

```
#just cleaning some unnessecary values from degrees_level
degree_level = {
'level_1':{'bachelor',' ba '},
'level_2':{'masters',' ms ',' m.s ',"master's"},
'level_3':{'phd','p.h.d'}}

results = {}

for level, values in degree_level:
    results[level] = df.query(' or '.join((f"column_name.str.contains({value})" for value in values)), case=False, engine='python').count()
```

Something like that should work

Comment: I get an error: too many values to unpack, description column has 5000 entries. each entry is a string of probably 50-200 words. not sure if that would result in such error.

Comment: Corrected answer, needed to use sum() not count(). Also, I'm not too familiar with `iloc` but may still need to include that if that's how your df is populated.

Comment: still doesn't work. I added a sample string for reference.

Comment: So I guess.. where is this degree stored in the df?

Comment: ideally, I would like to replace the 30 within iloc and put an index like 'i' and have the for loop/ while loop like in C while i <= len(column). not really sure what is the equivalent in python.

Comment: there is a column with "job title", and another column "description".

Comment: added sample dataframe to the question

Comment: still error: too many values to unpack! I appreciate the help though! This is the dataset for reference https://www.kaggle.com/sl6149/data-scientist-job-market-in-the-us/home

Answer (score 0):

```
The simple way to do this breakup of text is by using n gram compare of text column by column. 
Create a list of position, company, location for possible values to be found.
Later compare the list column by column and save it in a data frame which can be combined lastly.

text1 = "Growing company located in the Atlanta, GA area is currently looking to add a Data Scientist to their team. The Data Scientist will analyze business level data to produce actionable insights utilizing analytics tools"

text2 = "Data scientist data analyst"

bigrams1 = ngrams(text1.lower().split(), n)  # For description 
bigrams2 = ngrams(text2.lower().split(), n)  # For position dictionary 

def compare(bigrams1, bigrams2):
    common=[]
    for grams in bigrams2:
       if grams in bigrams1:
         common.append(grams)
    return common

compare(bigrams1, bigrams2)

Output as 
compare(trigrams1,trigrams2)
Out[140]: [('data', 'scientist')]
```